# @font-face missing characters / glyphs in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-face

I'm having a strange problem while using `@font-face` on IE9. I converted a TTF of the typeface we want to WOFF, EOT and SVG using [font-squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

This worked seemingly well and I was able to use [Paul Irish's @font-face CSS](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) to get the type working on Chrome/Safari and Firefox. The problem is IE9.

When viewing in IE9, text using the font is missing characters. For example the phrase

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Appears as

```
 h   uick bro n fox ju p  o  r th  lazy do
```

I set up each font as a separate @font-face declaration to investigate further. Chrome (for example) renders the above phrase fine using WOFF, TTF and SVG. Bizarrely, IE9 renders WOFF and the TTF with the same missing characters. It does not however load the EOT.

Does anyone have any idea what the cause might be? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Comparison image showing the above visually]

*Edit 2011.19.12:* Thanks all for your answers, I've still not found a solution to this problem. As it happens, one of our designers has found another font that they want to use, rendering the question less critical, however I'd still like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: When you check the rendered source on the page, are all the letters there in HTML and just not displaying? Or are they not being rendered to HTML well?

Comment: They're all there in the rendered source. Bizarrely, when I copy and paste the sentence to notepad, for example, the characters are all there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like something is wrong with the way IE9 is rendering the format right but other browsers are... either (a) a compatibility issue with the font type, or (b) corruption in the conversion that IE can't handle? I could not reproduce the symptom so this may not be the true answer.

I would do fresh conversions with squirrel, and perhaps use script to detect browser agent and load the most IE compatible font-faces when necessary, and then the nice ones for Chrome/FF and other webkit browsers.

let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried converting the font again without success. Until I get this sorted I'm using `<!--[if IE]><[endif]-->` conditional tags to display a plain cursive font for IE.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer and awarding the bounty. I ended up using another font and can only assume that the problem is a corruption with the font that only affects IE. I still can't be sure, but this is the best explanation.

Comment: Thank you Liam. I'm sorry we couldn't find a better answer for you. I would add it to the IE quirks list. Glad you were able to find a suitable work around though.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer - file corruption is a good guess, it worked in my case. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<!--[if IE9]><[endif]-->` conditional tags to display a font that works in IE.

I would contact Microsoft about the issue, they might give a fix or roll out some hotfix on Windows Update or something.

Comment: See my comment on one.beat.consumer's answer - I'm doing this already. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @liam Oh sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem - two webfonts created via fontsquirrel.com had missing letters in IE9 but no other browser. It seems v9 is the only IE version picking up the .woff file for webfonts, and although other browsers used mine just fine, IE did not. Bizarrely, I solved this problem by using the command-line tool [sfnt2woff](http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/) which converts .oft & .ttf files info .woff files. I kept all the other webfont files that fontsquirrel generated, but replaced the .woffs on both broken fonts with those from sfnt2woff, and everything worked fine in IE9.

Comment: Is there any documentation for how to use this tool? I unzipped the file and don't know which file to open

Answer (score 0):

Try to experiment with the letter-spacing, this might help.

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2326571

Comment: Very useful find, but appears to be Firefox-specific. Nevertheless, I gave it a go but it I'm still missing characters in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact problem yesterday with fonts.com's webfont on IE9 only. Took us hours, but the .eof fonts we were using were somehow corrupted on fonts.com. In my case, we were self hosting the fonts, not via JS. So double check the fonts. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue today using Cantoni from MyFonts. Displays fine in everything but IE9. I'm using it for headers in a few places. The first one or two characters disappear on every header.

The only thing I did the managed to reliably fix it was adding a `&nbsp;` before the header for each missing letter. Not very clean and not too sure why it is working, but it does for me. Unfortunately, it then requires me to use a negative text indent to shift the header back over for it to properly align.